# OpenCV window disappears after a split second

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm studying [Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do) (O'Reilly, from Bradsky and Kaehler).

After compiling and running Example 2-3, the window created by `cvNamedWindow` (which is supposed to store/display a video) appears for only a split second.  Then it disappears.

Here's my code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL;
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos) {
    cvSetCaptureProperty(
                         g_capture,
                         CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,
                         pos
                         );
}
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Example3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
                                            g_capture,
                                            CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
                                            );
    if( frames != 0 ) {
        cvCreateTrackbar(
                         “Position”,
                         “Example3”,
                         &g_slider_position,
                         frames,
                         onTrackbarSlide
                         );
    }
    IplImage* frame;

    // While loop (as in Example 2) capture & show video
    // Release memory and destroy window

    return(0);
}
```

I'm using Windows 7, OpenCV 2.4.3, and VS 2010; I'm running the code from the command line.

What causes the window to close so quickly?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  I made some conversational/programming English edits.  Hopefully the diffs will be useful to you...  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14000577/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a while loop to capture and show video as in Example 2. After this release memory and destroy window. ;)

Comment: HEHEHE i spotted these comments at the bottom after my post, I managed complete this exercise and gradually progressing through the book, BUT i feel so LAME looking at this post heheheh well now i know i have to study the Example code more carefully rather than just stick it in my VB2010 and compile it loool. WELL THAT YOU ANYWAY HEHEH